# Dispose of SearchResultCollection after foreach-object

Tags: powershell, for-loop, active-directory, directoryservices

According [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall.aspx#Anchor_2) remarks, `.Dispose()` must be called on a `System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection` after you are done with it.

> Due to implementation restrictions, the SearchResultCollection class cannot release all of its unmanaged resources when it is garbage collected. **To prevent a memory leak, you must call the Dispose method when the SearchResultCollection object is no longer needed**.

I am also reading that you should use `Foreach-Object` instead of `foreach` to save memory because `foreach` requires the entire `SearchResultCollection` to be saved to memory before it can be iterated on.

```
$objSearcher.FindAll() | Foreach-Object { $_ }
```

is better than

```
$objResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach($objResult in $objResults)
{
    $objResult
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to call `.Dispose()` if you use `Foreach-Object`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `foreach` language statement is not equivalent to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, although they have similar purposes. (Unfortunately, `ForEach-Object` has a default alias of `foreach`, which IMO only adds to the confusion.)

My recommendation is not to use `ForEach-Object` when iterating directory search results, as `DirectorySearcher` is efficient and doesn't need `ForEach-Object`. (I also recommend `Write-Progress` as a part of your iteration, as `DirectorySearcher` might return a long list.)

`ForEach-Object` is useful when you want PowerShell's streaming behavior and you might not have an efficient search.

Answer (score 0):

Bill Stewart is right. `.FindAll()` returns an `IEnumerable` so it doesn't matter which one you choose.

But to your question of how to `Dispose` of the object with `ForEach-Object`, because of the above, you can store it in a variable first just like you did with `foreach`, then pipe that:

```
$objResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
$objResults | Foreach-Object { $_ }
$objResults.Dispose()
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to doing this over the `foreach($obj in $objResults)`?

Comment: "Is there any benefit in doing this?" No, not really.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan as Bill said, no there isn't. Because the object you're dealing with is an enumerator and not a pre-generated collection, it won't really matter; use what works best for your application. I was just demonstrating how to run `.Dispose()` if you chose this (as your question posited).